# Perform alert() everytime on opening Bootstrap modal, does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When I open a Bootstrap modal I want to perform an action, in this case an alert().
How do I check if a Bootstrap modal is open so I can perform an alert()?

I don't call the modal with a jQuery selector, I just let Bootstrap do that part of work.

This is my code but it doesn't work:

```
if ($("#myModal").data("bs.modal") && $("#myModal").data("bs.modal").isShown){
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: Why are checking if they are both true? Why not just || {}).isShown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap modal events :

```
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
alert('modal is now loaded');
}
```

Or you can use this event before the modal is shown :

```
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
alert('modal is not displayed yet');
}
```

[look Here for more information about JavaScript bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I have it figured out, it appears that my approach is the wrong way to do it, instead I should have called this inside a function:

```
$('#myModal').click(function(){
alert("myModal is clicked");
})
```

This way, the alert() will only show if the function has succesfuly executed.